Issue retrieving City/State/Zip line from block of text
I have a bunch of blocks of text that will contain address information such as:
Fake Name
Business name
60 N Address Ave.
San Jose, CA 95126
(555)255-5555
Email: emailaddress@aol.com

I need to extract the line with the city/state/zip but it can be on a different line in every block of text. I have tried using regex but am not getting any returned results. Any help would be appreciated!
function findStateLine(text) {
    const lines = text.split("\n");

    const regex = /\b[A-Z]{2}\b/;

    for (let i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        if (regex.test(lines[i])) {
            return lines[i].trim();
        }
    }

    return null;
}


const stateLine = findStateLine(text);
console.log(stateLine);


Expect the line from above 'San Jose, CA 95126' but am not getting any results
Also tried '/[\w ]+, \w{2} \d{5}/' as well in regex const but did not get results as well.

Try: /^\s*([^,\r\n]+)[,]?\s+([a-z]{2})\s+([0-9]{5})-?([0-9]{4})?\b/gim?

Your code works and I get San Jose, CA 95126

You can use this pattern:
/^\s*([^,\r\n]+)[,]?\s+([a-z]{2})\s+([0-9]{5})-?([0-9]{4})?\b/gim

Example


const regex = /^\s*([^,\r\n]+)[,]?\s+([a-z]{2})\s+([0-9]{5})-?([0-9]{4})?\b/gim;

const str = `San Jose, CA 95126
San Jose, CA 95126
San Jose, CA 95126-1234
San Jose, CA 951261234
san jose CA   951261234
san jose ca   951261234
san jose ca   9512612345`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
console.log(`${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
}



Details:

^ start of the line.

\s*: possible spaces.

([^,\r\n]+): extraction of city.

[,;]?: possible comma or any similar chars.

\s+: one or more spaces.

([a-z]{2}): state.

([0-9]{5}): zipcode.

-?([0-9]{4})?\b: possible dash and four other digits in the zipcode.


